# Probability of Sample space

Tags: probability-theory

I am confused why statement iii), is only true

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two possible events in a sample space $S$ and $A\cup B=S$.  Which of the following statements is always true:

(i) $P[A] + P[B] = 1$

(ii) $P[A \cap B] = P[A]P[B]$

(iii) $P[A] + P[B] = 1 + P[A\cap B]$

Since $A\cup B=S$, $A$ and $B$ must be mutually exclusive. Which means $P[A \cup B ] = P[A] + P[B]$

$P[S] = 1$

This means $P[A] + P[B] = P[S] = 1$,

$P[A \cap B] = P[A]P[B] = 0$ ,

$P[A] + P[B] = 1 + P[A\cap B] = 1 + 0 = 1$

So why is iii) always true and not i)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events $A$ and $B$ need not be disjoint. Take $A$ and $B$ both equal to $S$. Then
$$
P(A)+P(B)=2\neq P(A\cup B)
$$

Comment: Wouldn't $P(A \cap B) = 1$ , since they share the same elements?

Comment: Yes but the statement $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ is still false for another example. If we consider the toss of a fair coin and let $A$ be the event that a head comes up and $B$ be the event that tails comes up. Then $P(A\cap B)=P(\varnothing)=0\neq P(A)P(B)=(1/2)(1/2)$

Answer (score 2):

$A$ and $B$ need not be mutually exclusive, consider $A=B=S$

Answer (score 0):

The formula of addition:
$$1=P(S)=P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$